# Singular vs. Non-singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm asking this for clarification. A matrix/system of equations is singular is there are infinite solutions, but iff there is a unique solution then its non-singular?

I haven't learned how to take a determinant yet. However, my professor went over how to determine if it is singular or non-singular without needing to take it. I've looked in my notes, but haven't been able to find it.

Any clarity would be much appreciated.

Comment: *HINT*: Put the (augmented) matrix in echelon form. If the matrix is singular, there may be infinitely many solutions or there may be none at all.

Comment: For singular, there could be no solutions, and l think you meant determina*nt*

Comment: Determinants suck. Use row reduction.

Comment: A square matrix is singular if and only if it is not invertible. That may be the best way to get at questions about the number of solutions of a system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the linear system we have is

\begin{equation}
A x = b
\end{equation}

where $\newcommand{\reals}{{\mathbf R}}A\in\reals^{n\times n}$ and $x, b \in\reals^n$.

You need to be a bit more precise to be correct to relate the number (or existence) of solutions to the singularity of $A$.

The following statements are correct:

1. A linear system has a unique solution if and only if the matrix is non-singular.
2. A linear system has either no solution or infinite number of solutions if and only if the matrix is singular.
3. A linear system has a solution if and only if $b$ is in the range of $A$.

Now by definition,

1. The matrix is non-singular if and only if the determinant is nonzero.

However, like your professor mentioned, you do not need to evaluate the determinant to see whether a matrix is singular or not (though most such methods evaluates the determinant as by-product).

For example, you can use [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) to tell whether a matrix is singular. This has the following advantages.

1. The time complexity of Gaussian elimination is $O(n^3)$ (whereas brute-force evaluation of determinant by the original definition takes $O(n!)$).
2. Gaussian elimination evaluates the determinant as by-product (i.e., with no additional cost).

Hope this helps you!